# How to select branch name with EyeQL?

Tags: git, rest, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

Is it possible to select (return) branch name with EyeQL? Something like:

```
select revisions where ... order by date desc return revision,author,csid,branch
```

Because as I see, "branch" is unknown field in EyeQL...

Comment: It seems like 'branch' keyword is not possible. Here's a list of supported selectors: https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/eyeql-reference-guide-298976796.html. 
I think it's caused that Fisheye considers commit on a branch when a branch contains it (git branch --contains <commit>), so commit can have multiple branches.

Comment: @grzlew seems that you are right. Interesting is that branch field is available in " on <BRANCH> " statement of QL expression. But is not possible to be selected.